# How to import phonegap build into android studio

Tags: android, wordpress, cordova, android-studio

I want to turn my wordpress blog into an app to publish to the Google play store. So far I followed the instructions here http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-a-mobile-app-for-your-wordpress-site-a-diy-guide/

The build was successful and I downloaded the android apk file. How do I import this into android studio for testing and signing? When I tried to import project it tells me 'cannot import anything from myproject-debug.apk'

Comment: Android Studio does not import APKs

Comment: I see, then how would I test my app and publish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio does not import APK package. Not sure what you want to do that but be note that Android Studio does not sign apps by itself - it uses `jarsigner` under the hood. See "Signing Your App Manually" section of [official docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html), but since you use phonegap, you should check [their docs](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-android.md.html) in the first place. As for testing - just sideload your signed app (can be with debug cert) to any device or emulator.